# How to make file writable from read only in LibreOffice?

Tags: eclipse, xlsx, libreoffice-calc

I'm using `xlsx` file to store testdata in eclipse. I have closed the eclipse while the above mentioned file was open. I have closed that file too without save later.

Now If i open the eclipse and open the file or open that file direct from the location it shows below message :

> Document file 'StagingTestData.xlsx' is locked for editing by:
>
> Unknown User
>
> Open document read-only or open a copy of the document for editing.

[image]

I tried to allow the read write and execute permission for all but no success.
If i rename the file then its working fine. Can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu, actually the locked file was hidden so whenever I'm going to open the file it opens that file in locked mode

For solution.

1. Navigate to that directory where file exist
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> , It will show that hidden files here
3. Delete the locked file and now open the xlsx, it will work